# How to convert go test report.json to human readble

Tags: go

To generate a report file to Sonarqube, we use the following command:

```
go test -coverprofile cover.out ./... -json > report.json
```

The file `report.json` works well with Sonar. But the problem is, when test fails, we `cat report.json`, but it's very painful to find exact failure test case from the json format of output.

I am trying to avoid to create my own tool to parse report.json file, so I wonder if there is standard go tool to convert report.json to a human readable text format?

Comment: There is not a standard Go tool that converts the JSON format to a human readable format, but there is a [tool](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/test2json) that converts the human readable format to JSON.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I know the `test2json` tool. I tried this way: 1) `go test -v -coverprofile cover.out ./... > report.txt` then 2) `cat report.txt | go tool test2json > report.json`. But this way report.json will miss timestamp and package info.

Comment: I'd suggest to write a little tool in Go that reads the data from the report you are interested in and prints to stdout in the format you prefer. You should be up and running in 10min and then you can focus on how to format it nicely.